# How do you remove an RDS data layer from an Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do you remove an RDS database from an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

There doesn't appear to be an option to do this.  I understand I can create an EB environment and have it create an RDS server with it, which we did.  Now we just want to get raid of the RDS server by itself but leave the app servers running.  I don't see how we're suppose to do this unless I just delete it from the RDS GUI, but I'd think the proper way to do it is remove it from the EB environment.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No we did not, we ended up just not using the Elastic Beanstalk RDS setting.  We found it much easier just to keep RDS a lone and only use EB to autoscale our web servers.  After this issue we decided to not stick our databases in it.

Answer (score 22):

According to this answer on Amazon aws forums:

> There is currently no way to remove RDS from an Elastic Beanstalk
>   configuration. You would need to create a new Elastic Beanstalk
>   application configuration that excludes the RDS configuration, launch
>   your app in this new environment, and then change DNS to point to the
>   new environment.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=469364

Comment: one question, what if I remove the RDS instance from RDS console. Will it delete the Elastic Bean stalk Environment also ?

Comment: No it won't.  It will still show in the Data Tier even though the RDS instance has been deleted.

Comment: If you remove the RDS instance via the RDS console you can not change the configuration of the Elastic Bean anymore. The change will always generate an error because it could not find the RDS instance...

Comment: @Karda ugh, I was about to do that, thanks for the tip. I guess the best solution is to create a new elastic beanstalk application

Comment: in my case I had deleted the RDS instance, and started a new RDS from snapshot. Now the EB won't let me do `eb deploy` because it gives an error that `CloudFormation Stack missing... no DB instance *****`, com'on amazon. Now I am creating a new EB application.

Answer (score 7):

It's 2019 and still not possible to remove an RDS database from an Elastic Beanstalk environment. I wish I had known this earlier.

Anyway ... here are the general steps necessary to create a new environment without a managed RDS DB (based on the same [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=469364) from the AWS forum):

1. Create a snapshot of your RDS DB and create a new RDS DB from it. This does not retain the security group, parameter group, or options of your DB. So it might be preferable to create a new empty RDS DB where you can configure everything and then restore the contents from a DB dump like `mysqldump`.
2. Save a configuration of your Elastic Beanstalk env and download it from your S3 EBS bucket under `resources/templates/<your-app-name>/`.
3. Modify the config to remove all references to RDS, and upload the modified file to your S3 bucket.
4. Create a new environment from the saved configuration. You should now have an env without a managed RDS DB. Some settings might not be carried over in this process. For example, I had to reconfigure the load balancer for my new env.
5. Once everything is working in the new env you can use "Swap Environment URLs" or point your DNS record to the new load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can decouple the database from your environment.

Then it will follow the data retention policy you have set for it.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decouple-rds-from-beanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using the EB CLI that does not involve creating a replacement EB environment. For my use case, it was much more practical to modify the existing EB Environment and not have to go through the extra steps (and wait time) associated with creating a new environment and making sure all the settings propagated correctly.

TL;DR: Using the `eb config` feature, you can modify the settings for your existing environment and it will apply the change correctly.

Steps:

1. Enable termination protection on my RDS instance
2. Update ENV VARS for the EB environment to pass the hostname and port (once decoupled, ElasticBeanstalk will no longer provide these automatically in the preconfigured RDS_HOSTNAME and RDS_PORT env vars).
3. Run `eb config` to open an editor. In the `aws:rds:dbinstance` section (for me, it was at the bottom), change `DBDeletionPolicy` to `Retain`
4. Save and exit
5. EB will automatically update your environment configuration
6. Run `eb config` to open an editor. In the `aws:rds:dbinstance` section, change `HasCoupledDatabase` to `'false'`
7. Save and exit
8. EB will automatically update your environment configuration

Original post for this solution: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/decouple-rds-from-beanstalk#COG3pCkfJlRKa9_W9f6Bd7Xw