# How to delete database configuration attached to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I am having problems do deploy my application. It shows: Failed to deploy configuration because DBInstance not found.

Do you know how can I change the configuration since the DBInstance does not exist?

I already deleted the DBInstance through the RDS AWS Console but the elastic beanstalk configuration is still looking for the DB instance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove an RDS data layer from an Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614796/how-do-you-remove-an-rds-data-layer-from-an-elastic-beanstalk-environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. There is a [thread about this on the AWS Dev Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=469364), including a few ways to mitigate. You will need to create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment. I strongly suggest managing your RDS instances outside of your EB environment.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you so I started to managed my RDS instances outside of my EB environment but then I when I deleted the old RDS instance I got this problem.